# What happens when ajax call is invoked?

Tags: ajax, html, video

What happens when we create setTimeout or Ajax call?

I have a problem with invoking autoplay in HTML5 player on iPad.

If I call thing like that:

`function playItem()

{

    var playerArea = $('#playerArea');

    var flowplayerAjdi = getFlowplayerId();

    playerArea.empty();         


    playerArea.append(createQualityChooserHTML()+'');
    clipProperties.url = 'http://192.168.100.107:1935/ia/live/playlist.m3u8';

    playLiveFlowplayer(flowplayerAjdi, getWowzaUrl('ia'), '', '', true, true);

}`

everything works fine. But you can see that url is hardcoded - it has to be assigned by ajax call. So here is what I did:

`function playItem()

{

            $.ajax({

                url : 'playVODServlet',

                type : 'GET',

                data : JSON.stringify(playItemParams),

                timeout : 5000,

                dataType : "json",

                error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)

                {

                    console.error("Error");

                },

                success : function(searchResult)

                {

                    var playerArea = $('#playerArea');

                    var flowplayerAjdi = getFlowplayerId();

                    playerArea.empty();


                    playerArea.append(createQualityChooserHTML()+'');

                    clipProperties.url = searchResult.assetId;

                    playLiveFlowplayer(flowplayerAjdi, getWowzaUrl('ia'), '', '', true, true);  


                }

            });`

}

An how autostart doesn't work. So my question is: what could be the problem? It looks it is related with ajax call breaks normally code execution and creates error and success function. Same thing happens if I put player constructor to setTimeout.

Comment: why don't you debug it? it's obvious the problem is in searchResult.assetId. put a breakpoint inside success function and see what are the values in searchResult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phones & tablets do not allow you to autoplay audio/video. This is precaution so the user doesn't get a hefty bill because your application automatically streamed video/audio.

You could try triggering a click event on the player once your page has loaded, but I doubt it'll work.